# HTML Javascript Combine SRC, Link, ALT tags

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I am wondering if anyone knows a way to combine the "a href", "img src", and "alt" tags. We deal with a large amount of images and it is pretty tedious copying and pasting the same thing for all three fields for each picture in dreamweaver. Doing it once would be ideal. From what I have seen there is probably not much of a chance in doing this. I am using either HTML or Javascript.

```
<a href="../../0_Images/CRG_UnitType.jpg" target="_blank">
<img src="../../0_Images/CRG_UnitType.jpg" alt="CRG_UnitType.jpg" width="775" height="617" border="2" class="picture">
</a>
```

Comment: Combine how? What does it mean to combine tags? Haven't you "combined" them right there in your sample HTML??

Comment: By the way I spent weeks researching this and couldn't find anything on it, which is why I posted here. Dont understand the -2.

Answer (score 1):

[AngularJS](http://www.angularjs.org) can also solve this problem. Source it in your HTML and set up a controller that includes your image data, and then you can use ng-repeat. The result is something like this.

```
<div ng-repeat="image in images">
    <a href ="{{image.href}}" target="_blank">
        <img SRC="{{image.src}}" width="{{image.width}}" height="{{image.height}}" border="2" class="picture">
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: There have been some good suggestions. I will check each of them out to see what works best. I will reply back once I get one working. It is really hard to get our IT to approve downloading of new software. Wish me luck.

Comment: I deal with the same thing. Everybody does. I found these two ([1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15012542/3403036),[2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20362291/3403036)) Stack Overflow answers to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your alt attributes should not contain your image file name, they should be used to describe the content of images in case they don't load, or in case someone visually impaired navigate through your website.

To answer the question, you definitivly need to use some server-side language to save time.
You could for instance display all your images quite easily with PHP by looping through an array of files and titles.

You need some basic understanding of this language (or any other server-side language) before doing so but the time you'll spend doing so won't be lost.

Comment: We put the description in the filename of what the content is so we just copy and paste it for the alt. There is no need to making alt different. These pages are for electronic process pages only the builders see and not for the general public.

Comment: Then why not leave alt blank? `alt=""`

Comment: Sorry taken so long to get back. Been busy with other tasks. We need alt because management and engineers wants it that way. :).

Answer (score 0):

It's possible,

you can use jquery to do what you want, and if the src is the same of the href as in your example the way is:

*In HTML use only image, and place an additional class:*

```
<img src="../../0_Images/CRG_UnitType.jpg" alt="CRG_UnitType.jpg" width="775" height="617" border="2" class="picture auto_add_link">
```

*Now add jquery function:*

```
$( ".auto_add_link" ).wrap(function() {
  return '<a href="' + $(this).attr("src") + '" target="_blank"></a>';
});
```

Not so pretty, but it works

[Demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pKrW3/)