# Angularize a jQuery application: what are the advantages?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Let's say I have a simple landing page with a bunch of jQuery effects and I want to "angularize it" (use *AngularJS*). I have a contact form and for that, no doubt, it can be made easily through *AngularJS*.

Consider DOM effects, such as scrollspy or fading the fixed top navbar, when the user scrolls down the page. Should these be made in AngularJS, maybe through the ngAnimate module, or is jQuery the best way?

What would be the advantages of using *AngularJS* over *jQuery*?

EDIT

In addition, in terms of compatibility, could AngularJS effects create some headaches? e.g. IE doesn't support CSS3 animations.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: I don't agree with you. This question could be really interesting and reach a pretty good audience.

Comment: OK Sir, as you say, nothing personal :)

Comment: both are more ore less heavy librarys you seem to only need a bit of it and both its plain javascript

Comment: Isn't this covered in [How do I “think in AngularJS”...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)?

Comment: @icc97 thank you. that post responds almost completly to my doubts

Answer (score 1):

That is the question you should ask yourself before rewriting any application in yet another framework. Sure, now Angular is the new kid on the block and Angular people tend to speak bad about jQuery, which suddenly is 'not anymore cool to use' or whatever. So before you plan an rewriting stuff with the latest alpha of Hype.js ask yourself why you would do that (for learning purposes could be a valid reason).
But if your site works with jQuery I don't see any reason or advantage at all to rewrite it in Angular. Use the right tool for the right job, and not a huge javascript framework for a simple page with a contact form (is my take on it). YMMD.

See also this answer, basically to the same question: [What does AngularJS do better than jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18414012/why-use-angularjs-instead-of-jquery?rq=1)