# AngularJS vs JQuery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, web-applications

I am a beginner-intermediate in web design and development, and I am trying to build a web app of sorts.

This app is basically sort of a "Video On Demand" app where the user can stream locally stored movies on the app.

I am well versed in HTML and CSS have basic to intermediate knowledge on Javascript.

I have worked with JQuery before a little bit, but never worked with AngularJS before. My question is, for my app, which should I use?

I read that AngularJS is the preferred library for apps which use CRUD functions. If that is so, I should probably use Angular JS, right?

Also is it possible to use BOTH on the same app? Not that I want to do it, I just want to know if its possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes can use both but generally don't need jQuery for angular apps with exception of plugins that aren't available as angular modules. Angular is not only for CRUD either. Is great for interactive content and quick development. Overall this sort of recommendation request however is off topic here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does AngularJS do better than jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18414012/what-does-angularjs-do-better-than-jquery)

Comment: That's all I needed to know. Thanks :) Unrelated question to the topic, though... Why is this question off topic? I'm slightly new here so I don't want to ask bad questions. Is it because it violates the "avoid asking for opinions" rule? if so, my bad.. I must confess, I didn't really read through all the text on that page. Is there a seperate StackExchange site I can ask questions like this or am I on my own for questions like this? @charlietfl

Comment: Because library and framework recommendations are highly opinionated. This site is geared towards absolute code related problems. read more in help center and section of what not to ask

Comment: @charlietfl Will do. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JQuery 
- is a library used for DOM Manipulations
- Has nothing to do with models 
- don't have two-way binding feature
- becomes complex and difficult to maintain when size of project increases
- Sometimes you have to write more code to achieve the same functionality as in Angular

Angular
- is a MVVM Framework
- Used for creating SPA (Single Page Applications)
- Has key features like routing, directives, two way data binding, models, dependency injection, unit tests etc
- is modular
- Maintainable, when project size increases
- is Fast
and many more.

Basically jQuery is a single tool (solves one specific problem: dom manipulation) where AngularJS is a whole toolbox with all kind of tools for different problems  (routing, modelbindings, dom manipulation, etc.). Actually jqLite (subset of jQuery) is part of the AngularJS and you use it to solve the dom-manipulation thing.

You should go with Angular js for your Video streaming app.

You can use angular and jquery together. And to make it possible, we need to use directive in Angular. But according to me, at the moment isomorphic js out there. So web app usually uses nodejs, we will not need to use jquery anymore You Might Not Need jQuery. But in case you have to re-use some of jQuery libs, that's fine to go.

Comment: Thank you for your help :) I will use AngularJS. I have actually started developing it with JQuery and am about 25% complete. Guess I'm going to have to roll everything back ;) Oh well... Its all a learning process, I guess. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Without espousing my personal opinions on the two frameworks, I'll start by saying that you can definitely use both in the same app. The advantage of doing so is that you'll kind of get the best of both worlds and be able to take advantage of what each one does well. The main disadvantage is that having to go get both frameworks on page load is going to slow down your site a little.

If I could pick only one, I would choose Angular, but you shouldn't take my word for it.

I would recommend skimming [this article](https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/jquery-angularjs-comparison-migration-walkthrough) on the pros and cons of each and decide what makes sense for you based on your app's needs. Good luck!

Comment: jQuery isn't considered a framework. it is considered a dom maniuplation library with a solid ajax api

Comment: Thanks for your advice in helping me decide :) That site is very useful @jamoque