# What does jQuery do better than AngularJS?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

In this link [What does AngularJS do better than jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18414012/what-does-angularjs-do-better-than-jquery) described angularjs advantage.I can not understand why we always use angularjs and forget about forever jquery,if angularjs have many advantages.Is angularjs a complete replacement jquery?

Comment: jQuery is library and Angualrjs is a framework, there purpose is very different, so in my opinion its not correct compare them

Comment: I recomment you to take a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background?rq=1